# What is the most efficient way to strip mine in Minecraft Java?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a world on Minecraft Java, and I feel like the only thing I'm ever doing is mining for diamonds....I feel like there must be some strategy out there I'm missing or something, because i just Can't find them at a productive rate. I used to play Bedrock and I always found it easier to just strip mined at Y=10 or Y=11. I feel like this method is very good on Bedrock but much less productive on Java.

My strip mining consists of:

1. Mining at y=10 or y=11
2. Making mines 3 blocks apart
3. Using F3 menu to see what is under lava

I have tried the clay trick, using clay, facing Z, 8 block out, etc. etc.

Insofar this method does not work in 1.17.1, the version this world was created in.
Please I need some help, because I need those diamonds.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Does this answer your question? [What's the most efficient Minecraft mining strategy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8310/whats-the-most-efficient-minecraft-mining-strategy)

Comment: In regards to the "clay trick", [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387693/why-doesnt-the-diamonds-trick-work-in-minecraft-1-17/387704#387704) may help. Additionally, one of the "contributions" to the apparent change to the generation of diamonds is that 1.17.x is an "intermediate update". Additional blocks (such as the deepslate ore generation) throws off the normal generation of ore a bit, but this is [in preparation for 1.18](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387274/how-exactly-has-diamond-ore-generation-changed-in-1-18)

Comment: Just how many diamonds do you need?? Other than an enchanting table (which is pretty much a poor early game substitute for a trading hall), a jukebox and diamond blocks for decorative purposes, mining diamonds is pointless - get a bunch of villagers with good trades, a good farm producing resources to trade for emeralds, and you can buy all diamond gear you ever need. Disenchant in grindstone to get rid of junk enchants, buy all magic books, farm xp, apply the books - perfect gear without mining a single diamond.

Answer (score 0):

The method that you have just described is the method that I personally find most effective for myself. I've gotten stacks of diamonds from this method. Maybe you might just need to stripmine in a different area? Also, I suggest getting a fortune III enchantment on a pickaxe when you're mining diamonds.

Sorry that I can't be much help, I don't know any other methods apart from this one.